# Karma: Catch errors using jasmine & grunt

Tags: node.js, junit, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I do have some problems with me very special grunt-karma-requirejs-jasmine setup. Basically I have everything up and running and as long as test are defined properly in the spec-files everything ist just working perfect, resulting in an junit-XML-file showing me test success and test failures.

Now the problem:
If there is a problem with the scripts the tests run on (e.g. variables undefined, modules not available --> everything that causes a normal browser to throw an error), my Karma stops with throwing an error, which is the default behaviour. But what I really want Karma to do is, not to stop, but log it's errors to my junit-XML-file => so I have three types of states (success, failure, error) in my XML and not on my console.

How can I:
- get Karma to custom handle errors?
- get Karma to tell karma-junit-reporter what to log?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot guys!